# Interrupting clojure.core.async calls

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

I am trying to figure out how to write a clojure wrapper using asynchronous channels for a UDP socket.

Considering just the reading part, my goal is to read packets from the socket and put them into a `clojure.core.async` channel. Independent of whether I use a `DatagramChannel` or `DatagramSocket`, reading would require some blocking calls like `Selector.select()` or `DatagramSocket.receive()`, which should be put in a loop in a separate thread.

**How should I properly stop the receiving thread in this case?** In pure Java, I would send an interrupt to the thread, which would stop the blocking read with an `InterruptedException`, but I am unfamiliar with `clojure.core.async`, and I don't know how `>!!` reacts to interrupt.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is [close the channel](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/close!). Then, the receiver will read `nil` on the next read.  `async` uses `nil` as a sentinel value to indicate "channel closed" to readers.  Note this means you cannot send `nil` over the channel as a normal piece of data, as readers will misinterpret it as meaning "channel closed" (you would have to replace `nil` data with `:my.proj/nil` or something).

Then the receiving thread can simply exit whatever loop it is in, and the Thread object will be cleaned up as normal.

See also [the infamous Hot Dog Machine example](https://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/) (yum!).